# Calculate created time between same file in 2 folders

Tags: powershell

I need to measure the time of a **SAME** file that is created in 2 different folders.

Example: `folder1\test.txt` and `folder2\test.txt`

Use `Get-Date` for each file, and the seconds difference between those.

The script need to keep running and creating a log for each file, containing the file name and the time difference in seconds

```
###start-process PowerShell.exe -arg C:\Users\Smap\Documents\logs\StartMonitoring.ps1 -WindowStyle Hidden

### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcherStart = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcherEnd = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcherStart.Path = "C:\Users\Smap\Desktop\MATHEUS\entrada"
$watcherEnd.Path = "C:\Users\Smap\Desktop\MATHEUS\saida"
$watcherStart.Filter = "*.*"
$watcherEnd.Filter = "*.*"
###    $watcherStart.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcherStart.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
$watcherEnd.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$actionStart = { $namefileStart = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
                 $changeTypeStart = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                 $timeStart = Get-Date
}              

 $actionEnd = { $filepath = "C:\Users\Smap\Desktop\MATHEUS\log\log " + ($namefileStart) + ".txt"
                ###$filepath = "C:\Users\Smap\Desktop\MATHEUS\log\log.txt"
                $namefileEnd = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
                $changeTypeEnd = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $timeEnd = Get-Date
                if ($namefileStart -eq $namefileEnd) {
                    $timeDiff = (NEW-TIMESPAN -Start $timeStart -End $timeEnd)
                    $logline = "$namefileStart, $namefileEnd, $timeStart, $timeEnd, $timeDiff"
                    Add-content $filepath -value $logline
                }
 }


### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED
Register-ObjectEvent $watcherStart "Created" -Action $actionStart
Register-ObjectEvent $watcherEnd "Created" -Action $actionEnd
###Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
###Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
###Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}`
```

Comment: Use the `LastWriteTime` property from `Get-ChildItem` on each file and then use `New-TimeSpan`? Could also create a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/24/changes-to-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx) to know when to evaluate.

Comment: how do i check if the new file at folder1 is the same at folder2? because i need to calculate the time between same files.

Comment: i've edited the question, can you look what is wrong?

Comment: So in each watcher you could pull the time for one file from the watcher, but then you would need to query the other file. If you know for certain that one file is going to be created first and not change, you then only need one watcher on the file that is changing. If not you'll need to a second watch with the duplicated full action on the watcher.